# grails I18N message properties file with US states

Tags: grails

How would I go about setting up a I18N message properties file with all the US states. I want to be able to add these to a g:select tag in my gsp file. 
I'm spinning my head seeing different ways online to do this. And being new to grails isn't helping. Any help appreciated.

Example:

```
<select> 
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
.......
</select>
```

Comment: this could be very easy

Comment: Ok great because i'm not finding it easy. Maybe someone can give me a clue?

Comment: At this stage I don't even care if it's in a I18N file. Just want to know how to use g:select to generate states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple ways to do this....

In Config.groovy:

```
com.app.states=[[abbr: 'AL', name: 'Alabama'],[abbr: 'AK', name: 'Alaska']..........]
```

Then in your gsp:

```
<g:select name="state" from="${grailsApplication.config.com.app.states}" optionKey="abbr" optionValue="name" noSelection="${['null':'Select One...']}" value="${obj.state}"/>
```

**Another way**

Make an enum for your abbreviations:

```
package com.app.enum
public enum State {
    AL, AK, .........., WY
}
```

Add messages in messages.properties:

```
com.app.enum.AL=Alabama
com.app.enum.AK=Alaska
...
...
...
```

Then in your GSP:

```
<g:select name="state" from="${com.app.enum.State.values()}" optionKey="key" valueMessagePrefix="com.app.enum" noSelection="${['null':'Select One...']}" value="${obj.state.key}"/>
```

I kinda preffer the second way.  I would also type the state field on my model as the State enum type instead of just a String.  But either of these should work for you...

Comment: Sorry, just re-read your question.  The first one doesn't really solve the i18n issue.  You could probably add'valueMessagePrefix' to the g:select there, and do similar though.  You would just want to take off the 'optionValue' from the tag.